# Convert plist format text to json format

Tags: json, collections, hashmap, plist, apache-cayenne

Application uses Apache Cayenne.

I receive a string in the following format. This string is available for me in HashMap format as well.

```
{And=[(effectiveDate >= Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 EDT 2015), {And=[(loanType = 2), {Or=[{And=[{Not=[(specialFeaturesString like "*003* ")]}, {Not=[(specialFeaturesString like "*007*")]}]}, (specialFeaturesString like "*007*")]}, (specialFeaturesString like "*808*")]}]}
```

I would like to covert the above string to json format like below

```
{ "condition": "AND", "rules": [ { "id": "eDate", "field": "eDate", "type": "date", "input": "text", "operator": "greater_or_equal", "value": "2015/09/01" }, { "condition": "AND", "rules": [ { "id": "loanType", "field": "loanType", "type": "string", "input": "text", "operator": "equal", "value": "2" }, { "condition": "OR", "rules": [ { "id": "specialFeatureText", "field": "specialFeatureText", "type": "string", "input": "text", "operator": "equal", "value": "*707*" }, { "condition": "AND", "rules": [ { "id": "specialFeatureText", "field": "specialFeatureText", "type": "string", "input": "text", "operator": "not_equal", "value": "*003*" }, { "id": "specialFeatureText", "field": "specialFeatureText", "type": "string", "input": "text", "operator": "not_equal", "value": "*007*" } ] } ] }, { "id": "specialFeatureText", "field": "specialFeatureText", "type": "string", "input": "text", "operator": "equal", "value": "*808*" } ] } ] }
```

I may have to create POJOs and loop through the Map to to achieve this. Perhaps some recursion is involved.

I eventually feed the above json to jquery querybuilder.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jackson JSON serializer to convert your HashMap or POJO to JSON in appropriate format. E.g.:

```
Map<String, Object> mapMatchingJsonStructure = ...
OutputStream out = // where you want to write the output
new ObjectMapper().writeValue(out, mapMatchingJsonStructure);
```

Also Cayenne has a plist parser in [cayenne-wocompat](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.cayenne.modeler%7Ccayenne-wocompat%7C4.0.M3%7Cjar). This is less relevant to you, as you already have your plist parsed. But I thought I'd mention.